Filter datetime column with object as data type in python
I have a df with a Timestamp and Value columns. Both have the 'object' dtype
|       Timestamp          |  Value  |
--------------------------------------
| 8/21/2023 12:00:00 AM    |    a    |
| 11/22/2023 12:00:00 AM   |    b    |
| 3/7/2022 12:00:00 AM     |    c    |

I would like to filter the df on the timestamp columns. For example get results before 6/1/2022 which should give me this:
|       Timestamp          |  Value  |
--------------------------------------
| 3/7/2022 12:00:00 AM     |    c    |

I don't need the time in the column either. Just the date should suffice.
Need help converting the dtype from object to datetime if that's the first step. After that, do i filter it?
Thank you in advance!

Convert to_datetime, then filter it using the format YYYY-MM-DD
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
df = df[df["Timestamp"] < "2022-06-01"]

   Timestamp Value
2 2022-03-07     c


Thank you @e-motta! A follow-up. If I want to filter all records less than 11/22/2023, how do i do this? df = df[df["Timestamp"] < "11/22/2023"] or df = df[df["Timestamp"] <= "11/21/2023"]  does not filter out the record with 11/22/2023 timestamp.

@adityatandel you have to use the format YYYY-MM-DD: '2023-11-22', '2023-11-21'.

my apologies. i used the ' YYYY-MM-DD' format. I got an error when i ran df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"]). /var/folders/lp/4fmp6zz13gj6rbtx1k3wbqp00000gp/T/ipykernel_46030/4274785559.py:1: UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to dateutil. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format. Could this be why the filtering is not working?

It works with no warnings for the data in the question, so the problem may be related to the rest of your data. Try converting to datetime specifying a format: pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'). If this fails, you may have different formats in your dataset.
